# Difference between nonzero(a), where(a) and argwhere(a). When to use which?

Tags: python, numpy

In Numpy, [`nonzero(a)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero), [`where(a)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`argwhere(a)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html), with `a` being a numpy array, all seem to return the non-zero indices of the array. What are the differences between these three calls?

- On `argwhere` the documentation says:

  > `np.argwhere(a)` is the same as `np.transpose(np.nonzero(a))`.

  Why have a whole function that just  transposes the output of `nonzero` ? When would that be so useful that it deserves a separate function?
- What about the difference between `where(a)` and `nonzero(a)`? Wouldn't they return the exact same result?

Comment: `where` gives the option to return from two different arrays, I think that's the main reason for it over simply `nonzero`

Comment: I expect the main reason is historical :), what np.where does in the other case is basically np.choose...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`nonzero` and `argwhere` both give you information about where in the array the elements are `True`.  `where` works the same as `nonzero` in the form you have posted, but it has a second form:

```
np.where(mask,a,b)
```

which can be roughly thought of as a numpy "ufunc" version of the conditional expression:

```
a[i] if mask[i] else b[i]
```

(with appropriate broadcasting of `a` and `b`).

As far as having *both* `nonzero` and `argwhere`, they're conceptually different.  `nonzero` is structured to return an object which can be used for indexing.  This can be lighter-weight than creating an entire boolean mask if the 0's are sparse:

```
mask = a == 0  # entire array of bools
mask = np.nonzero(a)
```

Now you can use that mask to index other arrays, etc.  However, as it is, it's not very nice conceptually to figure out which indices correspond to 0 elements.  That's where `argwhere` comes in.

Comment: I don't understand your last few statements. `np.nonzero(a)` returns a tuple, so `mask.T` is not allowed. `mask[:,0]` similarly does not work.

Comment: @Sam -- You're right.  Sorry about that.  (I was wrong about what it actually returns).  The point however is the same.  `np.argnonzero` is nice to get the indices which are not zero.

Comment: "This can be lighter-weight than creating an entire boolean mask if the 0's are sparse" - but you already have to create that entire boolean mask to feed it to `nonzero`.

Comment: (Also, I think you mixed up zero elements and nonzero elements.)

Comment: @user2357112 So ... It's hard to say exactly what I meant 3 years ago when I wrote this, but I'm guessing that indexing via an array with only a few elements will be faster than indexing using a mask that has `n` elements (where `n` is the size of the flattened array being indexed).  Also don't buy into the example too much -- What if you already had a suitable `mask` array sitting around?

Comment: @user2357112 -- Also, I'm not 100% sure I'm following your next comment either.  Having a (non-boolean) array that is useful for picking out the non-zero elements makes it hard to get the `0` elements.  However, _boolean_ array that can pick out the non-zero elements can easily be inverted (`~`) to pick out the 0 elements -- Though, I _could_ be missing something.  I wrote this 3 years ago when I worked with `numpy` a lot more than I have been recently ...

Comment: If you already have a suitable `mask` lying around, feeding it to `nonzero` is still going to be more expensive than not feeding it to `nonzero`. As for the next comment, the output of `nonzero` is small if the nonzero elements are sparse, not if the zeros are sparse. Similarly, the last paragraph sounds like it's talking about the difference between the use cases of `argwhere` and `where`, with the thing about finding 0 elements being a mistake instead of deliberate.

Comment: this doesn't explain the difference b/w nonzero and argwhere, just that one is lightweight.

Answer (score 10):

I can't comment on the usefulness of having a separate convenience function that transposes the result of another, but I can comment on `where` vs `nonzero`.  In it's simplest use case, `where` is indeed the same as `nonzero`.

```
>>> np.where(np.array([[0,4],[4,0]]))
(array([0, 1]), array([1, 0]))
>>> np.nonzero(np.array([[0,4],[4,0]]))
(array([0, 1]), array([1, 0]))
```

or

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
>>> np.where(a == 3)
(array([1, 0]),)
>>> np.nonzero(a == 3)
(array([1, 0]),)
```

`where` is different from `nonzero` in the case when you wish to pick elements of from array `a` if some condition is `True` and from array `b` when that condition is `False`.

```
>>> a = np.array([[6, 4],[0, -3]])
>>> b = np.array([[100, 200], [300, 400]])
>>> np.where(a > 0, a, b)
array([[6, 4], [300, 400]])
```

Again, I can't explain why they added the `nonzero` functionality to `where`, but this at least explains how the two are different.

**EDIT**: Fixed the first example... my logic was incorrect previously