# Basics of numpy where function, what does it do to the array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have seen the post [Difference between nonzero(a), where(a) and argwhere(a). When to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976697/difference-between-nonzeroa-wherea-and-argwherea-when-to-use-which) and I don't really understand the use of the where function from numpy module.

For example I have this code

```
import numpy as np

Z =np.array( 
    [[1,0,1,1,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,0,0],
     [0,1,0,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,1,0,0],
     [0,1,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0]])
print Z
print np.where(Z)
```

Which gives:

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], dtype=int64), 
 array([0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1], dtype=int64))
```

The definition of where function is: 
Return elements, either from x or y, depending on condition. But it doesn't also makes sense to me

So what does the output exactly mean?

Comment: When you call it as `np.where(condition, x, y)` it does what you have quoted. If you omit the `x` and `y` arguments is is equivalent to `np.nonzero`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.where` returns indices where a given condition is met. In your case, you're asking for the indices where the value in `Z` is not `0` (e.g. Python considers any non-`0` value as `True`). Which for `Z` results in:

```
(0, 0) # top left
(0, 2) # third element in the first row
(0, 3) # fourth element in the first row
(1, 3) # fourth element in the second row
...    # and so on
```

`np.where` starts to make sense in the following scenarios:

```
a = np.arange(10)
np.where(a > 5) # give me all indices where the value of a is bigger than 5
# a > 5 is a boolean mask like [False, False, ..., True, True, True]
# (array([6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int64),)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: does numpy.where loops the entire array?