# How to implement a simplified argwhere in cuda

Tags: c++, cuda

What would be the best way to implement a simplified `argwhere` in cuda. Basically, I want to write a kernel, that takes in two images of the same size and returns an array of image positions for which the values on both images are equal. Comparison is trivial, however, I am stuck trying to generate the resulting array. I don't know how to synchronize appending to the array across all the threads.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but what does `argwhere`  do?

Comment: [argwhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976697/difference-between-nonzeroa-wherea-and-argwherea-when-to-use-which)

Comment: Two approaches: 1. Handle it as a reduction/stream compaction ([thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) would be *great* for this).  2. Create an array in global memory that is initally empty, but allocated for a size large enough for all the comparison matches.  Then have each thread that finds a match atomically request a slot in the array.

Comment: Which approach would be faster if only a few pixel values (~1%) are equal?

Comment: Almost certainly the atomic approach would be faster in the low-density-match case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach would be to use a reduction/stream compaction approach, and in this case I think [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) would be an obvious choice.

Another possible approach, which should probably be faster than a parallel reduction if the match density is low, is to use an atomic-based approach, where each thread that finds a match atomically requests a slot in a global array, to store the match index.

Here's a worked example of both approaches:

```
$ cat t909.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

#include <iostream>

#define MAX_SIZE 1048576
#define nTPB 256

__device__ int match_indices[MAX_SIZE];
__device__ int next_idx = 0;

__device__ void add_idx(int idx){

  int my_idx = atomicAdd(&next_idx, 1);
  if (my_idx < MAX_SIZE) match_indices[my_idx] = idx;
}

template <typename T>
__device__ bool match_func(T &d1, T &d2){

  return (d1 == d2);
}

template <typename T>
__global__ void k1(const T * __restrict__ d1, const T * __restrict__ d2, const int dsize){

  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < dsize){
    if (match_func(d1[idx], d2[idx])) add_idx(idx);
    }
}

typedef thrust::tuple<int, int> mytuple;
struct my_comp : public thrust::unary_function<mytuple, int>
{
  __host__ __device__
  int operator()(mytuple &t1){
    if (thrust::get<0>(t1) == thrust::get<1>(t1)) return 0;
    else return 1;
  }
};

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(){

  thrust::device_vector<int> d1(MAX_SIZE, 1);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d2(MAX_SIZE, 2);
  d1[12] = 2; d1[16] = 2; d1[MAX_SIZE-1] = 2;

  //method 2
  k1<<<(MAX_SIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d1.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d2.data()), MAX_SIZE);
  int total_matches;
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&total_matches, next_idx, sizeof(int));
  int *matches = new int[total_matches];
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(matches, match_indices, total_matches*sizeof(int));
  std::cout << "Kernel results: " << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < total_matches; i++)
    std::cout << matches[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  //method 1
  thrust::device_vector<int> result(MAX_SIZE);
  int result_size = thrust::copy_if(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), thrust::counting_iterator<int>(MAX_SIZE), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d1.begin(), d2.begin())), my_comp()), result.begin(), _1 == 0) - result.begin();
  std::cout << "Thrust results: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy_n(result.begin(), result_size, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t909 t909.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t909
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Kernel results:
12,16,1048575,
Thrust results:
12,16,1048575,
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

As a final note, if you do a timing comparison of these two approaches, you will discover that the atomic/kernel method is noticeably faster when the match density is low (say ~1% or less), but the thrust approach is faster when the match density is high (say ~50% or higher).  The exact comparison will depend on the GPU you are running on and probably other factors as well, such as overall data set size.