# get indices of n-dimensional array when condition is True python

Tags: python, numpy, slice, indices

I have a 3 dimensional array. I would like to get the indices when the condition is met. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

x = np.array(np.random.rand(20))
x = x.reshape(2,5,2)

# x looks like this
array([[[ 0.69646919,  0.28613933],
    [ 0.22685145,  0.55131477],
    [ 0.71946897,  0.42310646],
    [ 0.9807642 ,  0.68482974],
    [ 0.4809319 ,  0.39211752]],

   [[ 0.34317802,  0.72904971],
    [ 0.43857224,  0.0596779 ],
    [ 0.39804426,  0.73799541],
    [ 0.18249173,  0.17545176],
    [ 0.53155137,  0.53182759]]])

# now I want to get the indices where the value is less than 0.5
idx = np.where(x<0.5)

print idx 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]),
 array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]))
```

`np.where` returns the tuples. How can I extract the indices? like `[0,0,1], [0,1,0],[0,2,1], ...., [1,3,1]`

Comment: .. `np.argwhere`?

Comment: Use `np.argwhere()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976697/difference-between-nonzeroa-wherea-and-argwherea-when-to-use-which?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa